# Adding jQuery local fallback using document.write

Tags: javascript

I'm generating the jQuery script tag dynamically using a `Literal` control where the value of the .Text property is set like this:

```
jQueryTag = "<script src=\"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>";
TheJQueryTax.Text = jQueryTag;
```

I want to add a fallback to this, something like this:

```
jQueryTag = jQueryTag + Environment.NewLine +
"<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"/ExternalScripts/jquery1.js\"></script>')</script>";
```

The problem is that the first `</script>` tag seems to close the opening tag and then `')` gets added to the HTML document.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: but what is your problem? I mean ') is for closing your ('

Comment: @Neel: yes, that's what it's for but the first </script> that comes right before the ') closes the opening <script> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try old trick with splitting the string:

```
jQueryTag = jQueryTag + Environment.NewLine +
"<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"/ExternalScripts/jquery1.js\"><' + '/script>')</script>";
```